# Exception propagation in React Native

Tags: reactjs, exception, react-native, try-catch, throw

Here is a function `geolocate()` that calls geolocation service asynchronously in React Native.

The problem is that once an error is thrown inside `geolocationError()`, it does not get propagated to the parent `geolocate()`, but the red error screen appears immeadiately.

How to propagate the error to the `catch()` block of `geolocate()`?

```
  async geolocate() {
    try {
      let result = await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        this.geolocationSuccess.bind(this),
        this.geolocationError.bind(this),
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
      );
      if (result != null) return result;
    } catch(err) {
      // This doesn't get called
      Alert.alert(
        "Location unknown",
        "Turn localization services on.",
        [
          {text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK')},
        ]
      );
    };
  }

  geolocationError(err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err; // Stops here -> Promise.reject() does better job here, but still results in "Unhandled promise rejection"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Promise.reject()` seems to do the trick, but I still get an unhandled promise rejection.

```
[warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Location services disabled.
```